# How to store an uploaded file into a MySQL LONGBLOB column and view the uploaded file again?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to store an uploaded file (via ajax file upload) into a LONGBLOB column of a MySQL database. Reason for a LONGBLOB, the user is allowed to upload a file up until 10MB in file size.
The first issue is that I couldn't upload just the file byte[] into the column, as it complained about an "incorrect string value".
So, I decided to do a `Convert.ToBase64String` of the file byte[] and store that. No problem (I hope).

My main problem is that I want to retrieve that stored blob and write it to an `Outputstream` in order to view the file in the browser. The file is however corrupt.

The difference that I do pick up is that the byte[] length of the original file is significantly less than the byte[] of the blob (after I retrieve and convert it back to a byte[]).

So, code wise, here is what I have attempted for the saving of the uploaded file:

```
byte[] fileData = null;
//file is the uploaded file
file.InputStream.Position = 0;
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
{
    fileData = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
}    
var encryptedFileStream = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData);
//Storing encryptedFileStream to LONGBLOB type
```

Below is what I have attempted for the reading of the blob into a `OutputStream`:

```
var decryptedFileStream = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(file.FileStream)); //file.FileStream is a byte[] datatype.

WebClient client = new WebClient();
var response = ((Handler)ExecutionContext).Response;
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = file.FileExtension;
response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", (inline ? "inline" : "attachment") + "; filename=" + file.FileName);
response.AppendHeader("content-length", decryptedFileStream.Length.ToString());
response.OutputStream.Write(decryptedFileStream, 0, decryptedFileStream.Length);
```

Comment: "The first issue is that I couldn't upload just the file byte[] into the column, as it complained about an "incorrect string value". So, I decided to do a Convert.ToBase64String of the file byte[] and store that." First: Stop that. Go back. *Fix* the issues rather then doing something that wierd to sidestep it. That solution is deep into XY Problem Territory.

Comment: As for the Solution, HTTP Handlers can be used for this. It can retreive the data however it needs to and jsut respond as if the browser is reading the file from the file system. https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/how-to-create-an-asp-net-httphandler-to-serve-files-from-local-system/ Indeed a very common way to "download folders" is to get a .ZIP File and HTTP handler can actually create the .ZIP file on demand.

Comment: @Christopher, if that was your answer, then I would've accepted it. You were right, I had to look at why the "incorrect string value" issue was raised, and indeed, I was passing the wrong datatype to the MySQL proc...awesome